# Assume IAM role and then generate pre-signed URL in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to assume an IAM role and then use Amazon S3 by generating a presigned URL in order to access an S3 bucket in it.
This is how I have configured my code in Python :

```
def create_dynamicurl(key, expiration):
    client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object  = client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=3600,RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::123456789555:role/sample-S3AssumeRole',RoleSessionName='sampleSession',)
    temp_credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3' , aws_access_key_id=temp_credentials['AccessKeyId'],aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],aws_session_token=temp_credentials['SessionToken'])
    bucket_name = s3_resource.bucket
    params = {
        'Bucket': bucket_name,
        'Key': key
    }
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params=params, ExpiresIn=expiration)
    log.info('******URL******: %s' % url)
    return (url)
```

Is this the correct approach??

I was getting the error `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials` while running the code.

Answer (score 2):

I made slight modification to John's answer and now its working as expected:

```
    def create_dynamicurl(bucket ,key, expiration):
     client = boto3.client('sts')
     assumed_role_object  = client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=3600,RoleArn=123456789555:role/sample-S3AssumeRole',RoleSessionName='sampleSession',)
    temp_credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=temp_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                                    aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                                    aws_session_token=temp_credentials['SessionToken'])

    s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket).name
    params = {
        'Bucket': bucket_name,
        'Key': key
    }
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params=params, ExpiresIn=expiration)
    log.info('******URL******: %s' % url)
    return (url)
```

@John , thank you for the inspiration.

Comment: It appears to me that the line `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` would be creating a new s3 client as yourself, not as the assumed role. I believe you want `s3 = session.client('s3')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

After you Assume Role, you can use the credentials like this:

```py
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object  = sts_client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=3600,RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::123456789555:role/sample-S3AssumeRole',RoleSessionName='sampleSession',)
temp_credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

session = Session(aws_access_key_id     = temp_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                  aws_secret_access_key = temp_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                  aws_session_token     = temp_credentials['SessionToken'])

assumed_client = session.client('s3')
url = assumed_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params=params, ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

I didn't test it, but you should get the general idea.